# Bind model data to a razor .cshtml file to send via email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2, email-templates

I have a .cshtml file which serves as an order confirmation as html email.

Now I would like to read this .cshtml file and bind a certain viewmodel against the .cshtml file.

In the end I want to recieve a formatted html string to pass to my email message body.

How can I do this in an elegant way even if it needs 3rd party open source thats fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`RazorEngine`](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) NuGet which allows you to render a Razor template to a string:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });
```